# units of translation from an affine transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform

Let's say I use this function to find an affine transformation between two images like so.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform2d.html#d123e169460

[image]

```
[tform,inlierIdx] = estimateGeometricTransform2D(matchedPtsDistorted,matchedPtsOriginal,'similarity');
```

Is this the correct way to get translation?

```
trans_x = tform.T(3,1);
trans_y = tform.T(3,2);
Traslation = [trans_x; trans_y]
```

If so what are the units? Pixels?

Comment: the same units your points are.

Comment: Yes, pixels. Otherwise you'd need to input the size of a pixel to calculate the transform!